Movie about two lovers caught in awkard situation
In this movie, there are two persons: One Young man and One Young girl. Both are lovers. But after some time due to some misunderstanding girl left her boyfriend. Now in another scene, both of them are blackmailed by someone to wear some kind of helmet on their heads and maintain some distance and speed to reach some target and place something( probably bomb) somewhere.
I also think that both actor and actress were of Asian descent. I think it was recent.

Was the movie old or recent?

I think it was recent

Sounds like Kwik from 2011.

Gi-soo, Myeong-sik and Ah-rom were members of the same notorious motorcycle gang. They enjoyed their days roaming the streets recklessly on the motorcycles. Now, Gi-soo works as a motorcycle delivery man, Myeong-sik is a motorcycle cop and Ah-rom is a pop idol singer. One day, Gi-soo has Ah-rom riding on the back of his motorcycle as he makes a delivery. To his surprise the delivery package explodes. Gi-soo's cellphone rings and he hears a voice telling him that their is another bomb planted in his helmet which Ah-rom is wearing. Gi-soo is ordered to take another delivery. If the delivery is late or he attempts to run away the helmet will explode. 





Thanks Sir! I have a question. How are you able to tell name of movie so accurately?

I knew this one. Didn't remember the name, but Google and IMDb helped there.
